# Passing a context from GLSurfaceview

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am trying to run a obj loader.
I am using Java, OpenGL ES and Android studio.
I am trying to call a method using a context and getting errors.
The error is:

```
Model () in Model cannot be applied to (int, android.content.context)
```

The context I am trying to pass in is from `GLsurfaceview`. ie :
`glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new ObjRenderer (this));`

How can fix this error?
My code is below :

```
package com.android.objectloader.objectloader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class GroupObject  extends Model {
    String objectName;

    public GroupObject(){

    }



    public void setObjectName(String string) {
        this.objectName = string;
    }

    public String getObjectName() {
        return objectName;
    }



// Android Stuff!
public Context context;  // changed to public
private int modelID;


    public int Model (int modelID, Context activity) {       // return type is int
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<Model.Vector3D>();
        this.vertexTexture = new ArrayList<Model.Vector3D>();
        this.vertexNormal = new ArrayList<Model.Vector3D>();
        this.faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

        this.groupObjects = new ArrayList<GroupObject>();

        //this.modelID = modelID;
        this.modelID = modelID;
        this.context = activity;

        loadFile();
    }

    private int loadFile() {

       InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                       modelID);


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));

        try {
            loadOBJ(in);
            Log.d("LOADING FILE", "FILE LOADED SUCESSFULLY====================");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    private void loadOBJ(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
        Log.d("LOADING FILE", "STARTING!====================");
        GroupObject defaultObject = new GroupObject();
        GroupObject currentObject = defaultObject;

        this.groupObjects.add(defaultObject);

        String Line; // Stores ever line we read!
        String[] Blocks; // Stores string fragments after the split!!
        String CommandBlock; // Stores Command Blocks such as: v, vt, vn, g,
        // etc...

        while ((Line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Blocks = Line.split(" ");
            CommandBlock = Blocks[0];

            // Log.d("COMMAND BLOCK" , "---------- " + CommandBlock +
            // " ----------");

            if (CommandBlock.equals("g")) {
                if (Blocks[1] == "default")
                    currentObject = defaultObject;
                else {
                    GroupObject groupObject = new GroupObject();
                    groupObject.setObjectName(Blocks[1]);
                    currentObject = groupObject;
                    groupObjects.add(groupObject);
                }
            }

            if (CommandBlock.equals("v")) {
                Model.Vector3D vertex = new Model.Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]),
                        Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]),
                        Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3]));
                this.vertices.add(vertex);
                // Log.d("VERTEX DATA", " " + vertex.getX() + ", " +
                // vertex.getY() + ", " + vertex.getZ());
            }

            if (CommandBlock.equals("vt")) {
                Model.Vector3D vertexTex = new Model.Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]),
                        Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), 0.0f);
                this.vertexTexture.add(vertexTex);
                // Log.d("TEXTURE DATA", " " + vertexTex.getX() + ", " +
                // vertexTex.getY() + ", " + vertexTex.getZ());
            }

            if (CommandBlock.equals("vn")) {
                Model.Vector3D vertexNorm = new Model.Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]),
                        Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]),
                        Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3]));
                this.vertexNormal.add(vertexNorm);
                // Log.d("NORMAL DATA", " " + vertexNorm.getX() + ", " +
                // vertexNorm.getY() + ", " + vertexNorm.getZ());
            }

            if (CommandBlock.equals("f")) {
                Face face = new Face();
                faces.add(face);

                String[] faceParams;

                for (int i = 1; i < Blocks.length; i++) {
                    faceParams = Blocks[i].split("/");

                    face.getVertices()
                            .add(this.vertices.get(Integer
                                    .parseInt(faceParams[0]) - 1));

                    if (faceParams[1] == "") {
                    } else {
                        face.getUvws().add(
                                this.vertexTexture.get(Integer
                                        .parseInt(faceParams[1]) - 1));
                        face.getNormals().add(
                                this.vertexNormal.get(Integer
                                        .parseInt(faceParams[2]) - 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // fillInBuffers();
        fillInBuffersWithNormals();

        Log.d("OBJ OBJECT DATA", "V = " + vertices.size() + " VN = "
                + vertexTexture.size() + " VT = " + vertexNormal.size());

    }

    private void fillInBuffers() {

        int facesSize = faces.size();

        vertexCount = facesSize * 3;

        tempV = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        tempVt = new float[facesSize * 2 * 3];
        indices = new short[facesSize * 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < facesSize; i++) {
            Face face = faces.get(i);
            tempV[i * 9] = face.getVertices().get(0).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 1] = face.getVertices().get(0).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 2] = face.getVertices().get(0).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 3] = face.getVertices().get(1).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 4] = face.getVertices().get(1).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 5] = face.getVertices().get(1).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 6] = face.getVertices().get(2).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 7] = face.getVertices().get(2).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 8] = face.getVertices().get(2).getZ();
            tempVt[i * 6] = face.getUvws().get(0).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 1] = face.getUvws().get(0).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 2] = face.getUvws().get(1).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 3] = face.getUvws().get(1).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 4] = face.getUvws().get(2).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 5] = face.getUvws().get(2).getY();
            indices[i * 3] = (short) (i * 3);
            indices[i * 3 + 1] = (short) (i * 3 + 1);
            indices[i * 3 + 2] = (short) (i * 3 + 2);
        }

        _vb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempV.length * Model.FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _vb.put(tempV);
        _vb.position(0);

        _tcb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVt.length * Model.FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _tcb.put(tempVt);
        _tcb.position(0);

        _ib = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * Model.SHORT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        _ib.put(indices);
        _ib.position(0);
    }

    private void fillInBuffersWithNormals() {

        int facesSize = faces.size();

        vertexCount = facesSize * 3;

        tempV = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        tempVt = new float[facesSize * 2 * 3];
        tempVn = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        indices = new short[facesSize * 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < facesSize; i++) {
            Face face = faces.get(i);
            tempV[i * 9] = face.getVertices().get(0).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 1] = face.getVertices().get(0).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 2] = face.getVertices().get(0).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 3] = face.getVertices().get(1).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 4] = face.getVertices().get(1).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 5] = face.getVertices().get(1).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 6] = face.getVertices().get(2).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 7] = face.getVertices().get(2).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 8] = face.getVertices().get(2).getZ();

            tempVn[i * 9] = face.getNormals().get(0).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 1] = face.getNormals().get(0).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 2] = face.getNormals().get(0).getZ();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 3] = face.getNormals().get(1).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 4] = face.getNormals().get(1).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 5] = face.getNormals().get(1).getZ();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 6] = face.getNormals().get(2).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 7] = face.getNormals().get(2).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 8] = face.getNormals().get(2).getZ();

            tempVt[i * 6] = face.getUvws().get(0).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 1] = face.getUvws().get(0).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 2] = face.getUvws().get(1).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 3] = face.getUvws().get(1).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 4] = face.getUvws().get(2).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 5] = face.getUvws().get(2).getY();

            indices[i * 3] = (short) (i * 3);
            indices[i * 3 + 1] = (short) (i * 3 + 1);
            indices[i * 3 + 2] = (short) (i * 3 + 2);
        }

        _vb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempV.length * Model.FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _vb.put(tempV);
        _vb.position(0);

        _tcb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVt.length * Model.FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _tcb.put(tempVt);
        _tcb.position(0);

        _nb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVn.length * Model.FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _nb.put(tempVn);
        _nb.position(0);

        _ib = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * Model.SHORT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        _ib.put(indices);
        _ib.position(0);
    }

    public  FloatBuffer getVertices() {
        return _vb;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getTexCoords() {
        return _tcb;
    }

    public ShortBuffer getIndices() {
        return _ib;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getNormals() {
        return _nb;
    }





}`package com.android.objectloader.objectloader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_FLOAT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glDrawArrays;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glGetAttribLocation;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glGetUniformLocation;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUseProgram;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;


public class ObjRenderer extends GroupObject  implements Renderer {

        private static final String A_POSITION = "a_Position";
        private int aPositionLocation;
        private static final String U_COLOR = "u_Color";
        private int uColorLocation;
        private int program;
        private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
        private static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
        private static final int BYTES_PER_INT = 4;
        public FloatBuffer vertexData =  null;
        private ShortBuffer indexData = null;
        public Context context = null; // changed to public
        private int indicesSize;
        private int [ ] indicesRef;

//        public GroupObject GroupObjectReturn; //
        public ObjRenderer(Context context) {
            // this.context = context;

            new Model(R.raw.cube_obj, this.context);





//            float[] tableVerticesWithTriangles = {
//                    // Triangle 1
//                    -0.5f, -0.5f,
//                    0.5f,  0.5f,
//                    -0.5f,  0.5f,
//
//                    // Triangle 2
//                    -0.5f, -0.5f,
//                    0.5f, -0.5f,
//                    0.5f,  0.5f,
//
//                    // Line 1
//                    -0.5f, 0f,
//                    0.5f, 0f,
//
//                    // Mallets
//                    0f, -0.25f,
//                    0f,  0.25f
//            };


        }





        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
            // Set the background clear color to red. The first component is
            // red, the second is green, the third is blue, and the last
            // component is alpha, which we don't use in this lesson.
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

            String vertexShaderSource = com.android.objectloader.objectloader.TextResourceReader
                    .readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.simple_vertex_shader);
            String fragmentShaderSource = com.android.objectloader.objectloader.TextResourceReader
                    .readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.simple_fragment_shader);

            int vertexShader = com.android.objectloader.objectloader.ShaderHelper.compileVertexShader(vertexShaderSource);
            int fragmentShader = com.android.objectloader.objectloader.ShaderHelper.compileFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSource);

            program = com.android.objectloader.objectloader.ShaderHelper.linkProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

            if (LoggerConfig.ON){
                com.android.objectloader.objectloader.ShaderHelper.validateProgram(program);
            }
            glUseProgram(program);

            uColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_COLOR);
            aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);
            // Bind our data, specified by the variable vertexData, to the vertex
            // attribute at location A_POSITION_LOCATION.

           // glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, GL_FLOAT,
           //       false, 0, vertexData);
            getVertices().position(0);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, GL_FLOAT,
                    false, 0, getVertices());

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
            // Set the OpenGL viewport to fill the entire surface.
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
            // Clear the rendering surface.
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
            glUnused.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, );

            //         glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);



        }















    }

}
```

Comment: You can view the full project at Github https://github.com/divinechess/ObjectLoader/commit/1ed33d8fcef649fc7be4cafb17dacc7cd048c3ae

Comment: The word "context" has multiple meanings when used with GLSurfaceView.  It can refer to the EGL context, or to the Android Activity's Context object.  It sounds like you're interested in the latter, and this error is coming from the compiler?